# Big O, algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm wondering what is the big O notation for each of the below statement:

```
Sum = 0;
 for i=1 to N^2 do:
   for j=1 to N do:
    'Sum += 1;
```

Sum = 0 is O(1) for sure, because it will only be executed once.
But I'm confused by the second statement, should it be O(N) because it's the first loop? or it should be O(N^2) because N^2 is a quadratic function about variable N?

Comment: Not the count of the "for" instructions counts. The count of loops until the program is finished. This looks very much O(n^3)

Comment: Often it is assumed that an increment (or any addition really) is O(1). It isn't, really. It's really O(size of variable) or O(log value). Incrementing O(n) times however only takes O(n) time, see [the amortized analysis of incrementing a binary counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319377/regarding-binary-counter-amortized-analysis).

Comment: @harold Trying not to digress from the original question, but for the sake of OP I think a clarification is in order. When you do complexity analysis you often implicitly define how long certain operations take. In this case, adding to a pseudo-variable (which has a pseudo-type to boot!) is probably assumed to be `O(1)`. That wouldn't be the case if they were analyzing an algorithm for addition. I believe the CLRS intro to algorithm analysis talks about these assumptions. Another way to put this is, are you even sure that a hardware-level bit flip is `O(1)`? On which circuits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first loop is O(N<sup>2</sup>) because it executes N<sup>2</sup> steps.  Each of those steps executes the inner loop, which involves N steps, so there are N<sup>2</sup> * N or N<sup>3</sup> steps, and the algorithm is O(N<sup>3</sup>).

Answer (score 2):

You'll be looping through N three rounds..so i say: O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

```
Sum = 0; ~ 1

 for i=1 to N^2 do: ~ 1+2N^2
   for j=1 to N do: ~ (1+2N) * N^2
    'Sum += 1; ~ 1 * N * N^2
```

Time Complexity:

```
Time = 1 + 1+2N^2 + (1+2N)*N^2 + 1 * N * N^2

Time = 2 + 2N^2 + N^2 + 2N^3 + N^3

Time = 2 + 3N^2 + 3N^3

O(Time) = O(2 + 3N^2 + 3N^3) ~ O(N^3)
```

Comment: I'm curious about the `1+2N^2` term; where does the multiplier 2 come from?  Also, when it comes to the next line, `(1+2N) * N^2`, shouldn't that be `(1+2N^2) * N`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, (1+2N) * N^2 is the header of the N loop, multiplied by N^2 since it's inside the N^2 loop